# API for FB post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

What API should I use to share a post on FB.
I have tried using this

```
var o = {
    "og:title" : "Test " + new Date(),
    "og:url" : "http://www.123.com/work",
    "og:image": "http://www.clipartlord.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/train20.png",
    "og:description" : "This is the best train ever - Toy Train"
}


FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'Share',
    object_type: 'Announcement',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object:o,   
  })
    }, function(response){
  });
```

This shares the content directly on the wall and gives the user no choice to choose (friend, wall, managed page etc). What api would I have to use show this view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's the older version of the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

The current version is initialised like so:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

Or you can manually link to the dialog and put it in a popup (as shown in your screenshot)